# $('.nav-tabs > li a[title]').tooltip() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-3

Estou tentando inserir um wizard no meu sistema, e me deparo com esse erro:

[image: erro.png]

Estou usando bootstrap 3 e peguei um template pronto no [bootsnipp](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/Gqmz2)  e lá ele funciona perfeitamente. Não fiz nenhum tipo de alteração ainda, já mudei várias versões do jquery e não funciona.

Agradeço desde já a ajuda de todos!

Comment: Verifique se você incluiu não só o jQuery, mas também o Bootstrap.js na página. Você tem que se certificar de colocar esses dois antes de qualquer Javascript seu, onde definirá as coisas.

Comment: Está inserido sim @WallaceMaxters O que eu acho estranho é que outras funções como dropdowns, collapse funcionam perfeitamente.

Comment: Isso está acontecendo por que você não conseguiu selecionar nenhum elemento com o seletor `$('.nav-tabs > li a[title]')`.

Confira no console se quando você usa o seletor algum objeto é retornado.

Comment: Aparece isso @taiar : https://i.snag.gy/IDwzif.jpg . O engraçado é que, clicando no botão próximo, ele n funciona, se eu clicar diretamente nas bolinhas em cima ele funciona.

Comment: Cara, o seletor está errado. Faz a mesma coisa sem o `.tooltip()` no final. Você vai ver que tá recebendo um array vazio `[]`. Isso significa que você está selecionando errado com o xpath `'.nav-tabs > li a[title]'`.

Comment: Esse é o problema. Não aparece nada, sem falar que no site onde peguei o template funciona. To achando que pode ser questão de importação de bibliotecas